# Stumped by model manager's errant behavior when summing up/down votes and displaying an ordered list

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-views

This one might be tricky.

I have a basic web app where users post interesting URLs, and upvote/downvote the best/worst ones. I'm using **Python 2.7, Django 1.5**. Problem statement is in bold at the end.

In **models.py**, I have the following lines (*take special note of lines marked with **x***):

```
class Link(models.Model):
    submitter = models.ForeignKey(User)
    url = models.URLField("URL", max_length=250, blank=True)
x   with_votes = LinkVoteCountManager()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.url

class LinkVoteCountManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self): 
x       return super(LinkVoteCountManager, self).get_query_set().annotate(votes=Sum('vote__value')).order_by('-votes')

class Vote(models.Model):
    voter = models.ForeignKey(User) 
    link = models.ForeignKey(Link) 
x   value = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Next in **views.py** I have:

```
class LinkListView(ListView):
    model = Link
x   queryset = Link.with_votes.all()
```

This setup does the following: whenever a URL is submitted or voted upon, `LinkVoteCountManager()` sums its up/down votes and returns a query set ordered by the total.

Now for a FRESHLY submitted link, `LinkVoteCountManager()` should sum its votes to 0, since `value` in `Vote` is being set to 0 (by default). **But instead, I'm getting `NONE` for the vote count of FRESHLY submitted links, which totally messes up how the votes are ordered.** Why is `LinkVoteCountManager` behaving incorrectly for fresh links (yet working perfectly *after* the first vote has been cast). And how can I fix it? Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in Rene's answer, `Vote` object doesn't exist, which leads to `None` value for vote count. This, of course, makes perfect logical sense. I'm not going to overturn this logic, instead will re-work my ranking algorithm to ensure "None" votes are counted as '0'.

Answer (score 0):

There probably are no `Vote` objects for newly created links. In that case, the annotated `votes` attribute will be `None`. I don't know a straight-forward way of fixing this right now, but I would guess that you can solve this by using [F expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.F).